# insert 100+ variables into query string

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an online survey format with approx 200 input / select fields which I now want to write into my database. Now, since I dont want to go through the tedious process of writing out every single variable one-by-one in the query string, I was hoping that there would be an easier way, eg. using an array?

Comment: Does each field have its own column in the database?

Comment: yes, and I have written the $variable = $_POST['inputfield'] definition already. Its just about not doing duplicate work when writing the SQL query.

Comment: Please provide us more details and also what you have tried so far.

Comment: [Worth to read](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that I use. It requires that the database field names are the same as the `<input>` names:

```
$querystring1 = ""; $querystring2 = "";
foreach($_POST as $key => $var) {
    $querystring2 .= "'".$var."',"; $querystring1 .= $key.",";
}   
$insertquerystring = "(".$querystring1.") VALUES (".$querystring2.")";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mytablename` $insertquerystring") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Obviously using mysqli now instead of mysql!

Comment: this is genius, just what I needed. Just curious about the foreach($_POST) part, do I still have to manually write a definition for each variable (eg. $myvar = $_POST['fieldname'] or does the script automatically does tha for each incoming $_POST submission?

Comment: @Armitage2k that's a disaster. In fact with this code you will let anyone to manipulate the survey results through an SQL injection.

Comment: No, `$myvar = $_POST['fieldname']` is not necessary in this. You may want to do a mysql_real_escape_string on the `$_POST` beforehand, for security.

Comment: @YourCommonSense which is why I am wondering whether I still have to define my variables first, since I am using mysqli_escape on all of them.

Comment: @AdamB so final code would be for Mysqli and with foreach(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST) as $key => $var) ?

Comment: No, I would do `$_POST = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST)` before the foreach loop.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Obviously this solution is not a complete script. Any validation etc. would come on top of this. I was merely answering the specific question, rather than writing a complete system!

Comment: Whatever your reasons, the quality of this answer is just unacceptably low. It's a shame for both Stack Overflow and PHP community.

Comment: I disagree. I've answered a simple question with a simple answer in isolation. I wasn't asked to write a complete system. Normally a system would use a full framework. Snobbishness isn't helpful here.

Comment: @AdamB your script answers my question, the rest of the code I will naturally write myself. If there is anything that is a shame for SO, its that within 10secs after posting a question where I am seeking advice, I get a downvote. Thanks a lot for your help, appreciate you teaching me a new thing.

Comment: Thanks @Armitage2k . Yes there a number of people on SO who go looking around for things to downvote, rather than posting helpful responses. Good luck with your code!

Comment: @AdamB You don't have to write a "complete system" to protect this code against SQL injection. The problem here is that people will copy & paste your code without reading through the comments and they will be left with serious security issues in their application.